# oracle 11g not working while i'm login and in sql*plus i am getting ERROR: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-12154

Tags: oracle11g, ora-12154

my oracle 11g does not connecting my database while i'm login and in sql*plus i am getting ERROR: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-12154,i export few data from my oracle 8i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is TNS error.try  following

1. check your Tnsname identifier or host identifier name when u login
   to database that must match on tnsnames.ora file in ur
   C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\NETWORK\ADMIN .open tnsname.ora file
   in notepad and u find text like ORCLE =   (DESCRIPTION =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = JAMES)(PORT = 1521))
       (CONNECT_DATA =
         (SERVER = DEDICATED)
         (SERVICE_NAME = orcle)  -- THIS IS UR IDENTIFIER NAME.
       )   )

   EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =   (DESCRIPTION =
       (ADDRESS_LIST =
         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
       )
       (CONNECT_DATA =
         (SID = PLSExtProc)
         (PRESENTATION = RO)
       )   )

or

- restart your oracle database  search local services or services then 
  restart service like oracleserviceORCL

CONNECT SCOTT/TIGER@ORCLE